# PHP multiple attachment email shows up as text

Tags: php, email, attachment, email-attachments

=======UPDATE========

The problem ended up being that I was using the header ContentType when I should have been using Content-Type.

Thanks for your help guys.

Derp derp derp.

=======/UPDATE=======

I apologize in advance for the obnoxiously long question.

I'm attempting to send emails with attachments through PHP. I've done this successfully before with a single attachment. But I can't get it to work with multiple attachments, or for that matter now with a single attachment using this method. So, what am I doing wrong?

I understand that there are other libraries for these functions available. But I want to know WHY this one is not working.

Here is the method that generates the actual email:

```
function gen_mail ()
{
    $files = $this->files();
    $has_attachments = (bool) $files;

    $EOL = "\r\n"; // tried \n, PHP_EOL
    $message = $this->message;

    $headers = $this->gen_headers();
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0$EOL";

    if ($has_attachments) {
        $hash = md5(time());
        $sep = "=={$hash}==";
        $headers .= "ContentType: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$sep\"$EOL$EOL";
        $headers .= "This is a MIME-encoded message.$EOL$EOL";
        $headers .= "--$sep$EOL";
    }

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"$EOL";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: inline$EOL";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit$EOL$EOL";
    $headers .= "$message$EOL$EOL";

    if ($has_attachments) { // here go attachments
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $filename = is_numeric($key)? basename($value) : $key;
            $file = fopen($value, 'rb');
            $data = fread($file, filesize($value));
                            fclose($file);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $headers .= "--$sep$EOL";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
            $headers .= "name=\"$filename\"$EOL";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
            // tried Content-Disposition, attachment, and every combination
            $headers .= "Content-Description: inline; $EOL ";
            $headers .= "filename=\"$filename\"$EOL$EOL";
            $headers .= "$content$EOL$EOL";
        }
        $headers .= "--$sep--$EOL$EOL";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

And this is what the headers returned by the above function look like:

```
From: test@urbido.es
MIME-Version: 1.0
ContentType: multipart/mixed; boundary="==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961=="

This is a MIME-encoded message.

--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Travis, you are so cool!!!1!

--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="html.login.php"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: inline; 
 filename="html.login.php"

PD9waHANCgkNCiRoZWFkZXJfY29uZmlnID0gYXJyYXkoKTsNCiRtc2cgPSAnUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCBP
cGVyYXRvcnMsIGVudGVyIHlvdXIgT3BlcmF0b3IgSUQgYW5kIHBhc3N3b3JkIHRvIGxvZ2luJzsN
CiRtc2dfY2xhc3MgPSAnbm9ybWFsJzsNCmlmICgkbG9nZ2VkX2luKSB7DQoJJGhlYWRlcl9jb25m
aWdbJ2NvbnRyb2xzJ10gPSBhcnJheSAoDQoJCWFycmF5ICgndGV4dCcgPT4gJ1N1Ym1pdCBFbnRy
aWVzJywgJ2hyZWYnID0+ICdlbnRyeScpLA0KCSk7DQoJJG1zZyA9ICdZb3UgYXJlIGxvZ2dlZCBp
bi4gVXNlIHRoZSBhYm92ZSBsaW5rcywgb3IgDQoJCWNsaWNrIDxhIGhyZWY9ImVudHJ5Ij5oZXJl
PC9hPiB0byBiZWdpbiBvciByZXN1bWUgYSBqb2InOw0KCSRtc2dfY2xhc3MgPSAnc3VjY2Vzcyc7
DQp9DQoNCj8+


--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==--
```

I've tried functions written by other people, and they produce seemingly identical output. But when I send those headers with
    mail($address, $subject, '', $headers)

I get this in my inbox:

```
This is a MIME-encoded message.

--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Travis, you are so cool!!!1!

--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="html.login.php"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: inline;
 filename="html.login.php"

PD9waHANCgkNCiRoZWFkZXJfY29uZmlnID0gYXJyYXkoKTsNCiRtc2cgPSAnUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCBP
cGVyYXRvcnMsIGVudGVyIHlvdXIgT3BlcmF0b3IgSUQgYW5kIHBhc3N3b3JkIHRvIGxvZ2luJzsN
CiRtc2dfY2xhc3MgPSAnbm9ybWFsJzsNCmlmICgkbG9nZ2VkX2luKSB7DQoJJGhlYWRlcl9jb25m
aWdbJ2NvbnRyb2xzJ10gPSBhcnJheSAoDQoJCWFycmF5ICgndGV4dCcgPT4gJ1N1Ym1pdCBFbnRy
aWVzJywgJ2hyZWYnID0+ICdlbnRyeScpLA0KCSk7DQoJJG1zZyA9ICdZb3UgYXJlIGxvZ2dlZCBp
bi4gVXNlIHRoZSBhYm92ZSBsaW5rcywgb3IgDQoJCWNsaWNrIDxhIGhyZWY9ImVudHJ5Ij5oZXJl
PC9hPiB0byBiZWdpbiBvciByZXN1bWUgYSBqb2InOw0KCSRtc2dfY2xhc3MgPSAnc3VjY2Vzcyc7
DQp9DQoNCj8+


--==cd42448edf10bca4640bc7d6365e1961==--
```

Comment: You should consider using a library like Swiftmailer or some other to handle this for you.  It will make your life quite a bit easier.

Comment: I just updated the post. I know that there are great classes and libraries out there for sending emails. But I want to know why mine isn't working. I can't spot the difference between mine and others'.
Besides that, there are future needs for this particular application that are highly unlikely to be addressed by other libraries' mail implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the wrong header. It's "Content-Disposition", not "Content-Description". Try:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="html.login.php"
```

instead. Content-Description is to add a short DESCRIPTION of what the attachment is, e.g. "This is my resume" and has nothing to do at all with telling the mail client how to deal with the attachment.

Comment: I've tried Content-Disposition and Content-Description and attachment and inline, and every combination thereof. No luck, unfortunately. I've also tried using \n, PHP_EOL, and \r\n for the new lines. Still no luck. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try using PHPMailer/Swiftmailer and compare their output to yours. The difference will undoubtedly show you why your code isn't working.

Comment: That's an idea. I've tried using other people's code that works, and still couldn't spot the difference. But I'll give that a try.

Comment: I updated my code to make the output look just like Swiftmailer's, and it still would not work for me. The only observable difference being the headers Swiftmailer adds. But my ISP appears to be blocking my emails now.

Comment: I figured it out. I typed ContentType instead of Content-Type. D'oh!!

Comment: So, doing what you said in your response to my first comment did end up being what showed me the solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a solved issue, but I wnated to post a working function for all who might need it in the future. 
There are many example over net for sending multi-attachments email but most of them are confusing and non-working. I've got turibe function (I hope you do not mind) and reworked a little bit.

```
// priority: 1 (Highest), 2 (High), 3 (Normal), 4 (Low), 5 (Lowest).
function mail_attachment($files,$mailto,$from_mail,$from_name,$subject,$message,$bcc=false,$cc=false,$priority="3") {
    $EOL = "\r\n";
    $datetime=new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
    //sanitize
    $from_mail=filter_var($from_mail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $mailto=filter_var($mailto, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '',$subject);
    $from_name = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '',$from_name);
    $bcc = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '',$bcc);
    $cc = str_ireplace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $cc);


    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">$EOL";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <".md5(uniqid(microtime()))."@".gethostname().">$EOL";
    $headers .= "Date: ".$datetime->format(DateTime::RFC2822).$EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion().$EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Sender: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Priority: ".$priority.$EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0$EOL";
    if($bcc)$headers .= "Bcc:".$bcc."\r\n";
    if($cc)$headers .= "Cc:".$cc."\r\n";

    if($files){
        $message=nl2br(trim(filter_var(stripslashes($message), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
        $hash = md5(time());
        $sep = "=={$hash}==";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$sep\"$EOL$EOL";
        $headers .= "This is a MIME-encoded message.$EOL$EOL";
        $headers .= "--$sep$EOL";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"$EOL";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: inline$EOL";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit$EOL$EOL";
        $headers .= "$message$EOL$EOL";

        //here go attachments
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $filename = is_numeric($key)? basename($value) : $key;
            $file = fopen($value, 'rb');
            $data = fread($file, filesize($value));
            fclose($file);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $headers .= "--$sep$EOL";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
            $headers .= "name=\"$filename\"$EOL";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
            $headers .= "Content-Description: inline; $EOL ";
            $headers .= "filename=\"$filename\"$EOL$EOL";
            $headers .= "$content$EOL$EOL";
        }
        $headers .= "--$sep--$EOL$EOL";
    }else{
        $message=trim(filter_var(stripslashes($message), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    }

    $r=mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

   return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a shared host and have not been able to figure out how to use the PEAR mail features - everything I've read seems to assume that the reader already knows how to incorporate PEAR with an include('Mail.php') - but nobody says how to obtain the Mail.php file.  Urgh.

Anyway, my apps send emails infrequently and only to a few recipients at a time.  So I feel that using php's mail utility is fine.

Also, sometimes my attachments are dynamically generated so I left the chunk_split outside of the method so I can easily attach an actual file or just as easily generate the data and attach it as a file.

Here's a simple email class that has actually been tested:

```
<?php
class MyMail  {  

private function getMimeType ($fileName) {  
    $mime_types = array("pdf"=>"application/pdf","zip"=>"application/zip","csv"=>"text/plain","doc"=>"application/msword"
            ,"docx"=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
            ,"xls"=>"application/vnd.ms-excel","xlsx"=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            ,"ppt"=>"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","pptx"=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
            ,"gif"=>"image/gif","png"=>"image/png","jpeg"=>"image/jpg","jpg"=>"image/jpg","mp3"=>"audio/mpeg","wav"=>"audio/x-wav"
            ,"mpeg"=>"video/mpeg","mpg"=>"video/mpeg","mpe"=>"video/mpeg","css"=>"text/css","js"=>"application/javascript"
            ,"php"=>"text/plain","htm"=>"text/html","html"=>"text/html","txt"=>"text/plain");  
    $extension = explode('.',$fileName);
    $extension = end($extension);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

    if(isset($mime_types[$extension]))
        return $mime_types[$extension];

    return "application/octet-stream";
}

private $to = '';
private $subject = '';
private $returnPath = '';
private $attachments = array();
private $recipients = array('from' => '', 'reply' => ''); 
private $message = '';


public function setTo($s)  {  // comma separated list
    $this->to = $s;  
}   
public function setSubject($s)  {  
    $this->subject = $s;  
}   
public function setFrom($s)  {  // one email address only!
    $this->recipients['from'] = "From: $s";  
} 
public function setReturnPath($s)  {  // one email address only!
    $this->returnPath = "-r $s";  
}   
public function setReplyTo($s)  {  
    $this->recipients['reply'] = "Reply-To: $s";  
}   
public function setCc($s)  { // comma separated list 
    $this->recipients['cc'] = "Cc: $s";  
}
public function setBcc($s)  {  // comma separated list 
    $this->recipients['bcc'] = "Bcc: $s";  
}   
public function setMessage($s)  {  // be carefull to include strategic nl and spaces for text only presentation -- which uses strip_tags()
    $this->message = $s;  
}   
public function setAttachment($fileName, $data)  {  
    $this->attachments[] = array('name' => $fileName, 'data' => $data);
}

public function send() {

    $attachments = ( count($this->attachments) > 0 );

    $altMarker = '===_Alt_BOUNDRY_' . md5(uniqid(time()));
    $mixedMarker = str_replace('Alt', 'Mixed', $altMarker); 


    $txtMsg = strip_tags($this->message);

    $htmlMsg = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n"; 
    $htmlMsg .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">';
    $htmlMsg .= "\n</head>\n<body>\n";
    $htmlMsg .= $this->message;
    $htmlMsg .= "\n</body>\n</html>";


    $h = array();

    preg_match('/<([^<>]+)>$|^\bFrom: ([^<>]+)\b$/',$this->recipients['from'], $a);

    $nakedFrom = !empty($a[1]) ? $a[1] : $a[2];


    if( empty($this->returnPath) )
        $this->returnPath = '-r ' . $nakedFrom;

    if( empty($this->recipients['reply']) )
        $this->recipients['reply'] = 'Reply-To: ' . str_replace('From: ','',$this->recipients['from']);



    foreach ($this->recipients as $v)
        $h[] = $v;

    $h[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";

    if( $attachments ) {
        $h[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $mixedMarker . '"';
        $h[] = '';
        $h[] = '--' . $mixedMarker;
    }
    $h[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $altMarker . '"';
    $h[] = '';
    $h[] = '--' . $altMarker;
    $h[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1';
    $h[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
    $h[] = '';
    $h[] = $txtMsg;
    $h[] = '--' . $altMarker;
    $h[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
    $h[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
    $h[] = '';
    $h[] = $htmlMsg;
    $h[] = '--' . $altMarker . '--';
    $h[] = '';

    foreach( $this->attachments as $v ) {
        $h[] = '--' . $mixedMarker;
        $h[] = 'Content-Type: ' . $this->getMimeType ($v['name']) . ';';
        $h[] = '    name="' . $v['name'] . '"';
        $h[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';
        $h[] = 'Content-Disposition: attachment;';
        $h[] = '    filename="' . $v['name'] . '"';
        $h[] = ''; /* skip */
        $h[] = $v['data'];
    }

    if( $attachments ) 
        $h[] = '--' . $mixedMarker . '--';

    return (mail( $this->to, $this->subject, null, implode("\r\n", $h ), $this->returnPath) ? true : false); 
}
```

### }

---

### **- USAGE: **

```
$mail = new MyMail;  
$mail->setSubject( ' Testing 123 Subject' );
$mail->setFrom( 'me <testFrom@abc.com>' ); 
$mail->setTo( 'Anne Test <atest@example.com>' );
$mail->setCc('Jeff Test <jtest@example.com>, Mary Test <mtest@example.com>');
$mail->setMessage( "<h1>This is a test</h1>\n\n<p>This is a para</p>" ); // note the nl added in case mail opens as pure text...

// dynamically produced file data  
$mail->setAttachment( $fileName1,  
    chunk_split(base64_encode($attachmentData1)) );  

// attach actual file  
$mail->setAttachment( $fileName2,  
    chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('testFile.pdf'))) );   

echo ( $mail->send() ) ? 'sent' : 'oops';
```